# Kivy crash if __init__ includes Clock.schedule_interval

Tags: python, kivy

I am attempting to run an update method every 2 seconds but apparently this is not possible. I attempted to move everything around to various places but none of it worked. Is this a syntax/semantic error, or is there something wrong with my rig?

Edit: I also tried to put this code into some random method in which it correctly ran.

Here is the smallest possible code to reproduce my issue(sorry I just copied all of the dependencies):

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.graphics import *
from random import randint, random
from time import *
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial

class CliClicker(BoxLayout):

    auto_cc1 = 0
    auto_cc2 = 0
    auto_cc3 = 0
    auto_cc4 = 0

    score = 0 # ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self): 
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 2)
        print('I have been updated')

    def update(self):
        self.score += (self.auto_cc1*0.001)+(self.auto_cc2*0.01)+(self.auto_cc3*0.1)+(self.auto_cc4*1)

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CliClicker()


app = MainApp()
app.run()
```

Comment: add `super(CliClicker, self).__init__()` before `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 2)` and change `def update(self)` to `def update(self, _)`